# Brompton Dynamo Light Stopped Working

Tags: dynamo, brompton

My Brompton Dynamo light has been working perfectly since I got the bike about 8 months ago (the model is ‘Brompton spanninga dynamo tprbi06033’) however a few days ago when I changed the way it was mounted (this required opening up the rear light) the front stopped working. A couple of days later neither light is now working. I’ve looked at all of the connections - some were loose but they’re now back in place - but no luck. In the rear light there is a loose component (the size and shape of a £1 coin) and I can’t work out where it fits into. Is anybody able to help? Any videos/ tutorials would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Some photos of the rear light and the unknown component might make it easier for people to help you.